# Android Volley : ImageRequest deprecated

Tags: android, android-volley, deprecated

I'm on Android Studio version 1.4. I'm using the Android Volley library (I use the mcxiaoke mirror [here](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/)). But the `ImageRequest` is deprecated. The code still works but deprecated. Has anyone found an alternative for this?

I've search for this issue in Google but didn't find any solution.

[image: Screenshot 1]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

I think the class is not deprecated but the constructor that you are using is deprecated.

use this [constructor](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/9aba4f5f861ab547751aa572c8559467dfa59270/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageRequest.java#L72) instead of this [one](https://github.com/mcxiaoke/android-volley/blob/9aba4f5f861ab547751aa572c8559467dfa59270/src/main/java/com/android/volley/toolbox/ImageRequest.java#L89)

Usage example :

```
ImageRequest request = new ImageRequest(
                             url, myResponseListener, maxWidth,
                             maxHeight, scaleType, Config.RGB_565, myErrorListener);
```

Comment: thank you very much for pointing that out. Sorry for my noobness, very new to android.

Answer (score 3):

```
 button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            final ImageRequest imageRequest=new ImageRequest (url, new Response.Listener<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Bitmap response) {
                    imageView.setImageBitmap(response);

                }
            },0,0, ImageView.ScaleType.CENTER_CROP,null, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Some Thing Goes Wrong",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    error.printStackTrace();

                }
            });emphasized text
```

Answer (score 1):

I've used Square's Picaso library as an alternative. It works well; you can check it out at http://square.github.io/picasso/.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It looks interesting, sure i will try it later.

Comment: Although picasso is great, i suggest to just use volley for everything, stringrequest, jsonrequest, imagerequest. So you can benefit from lower app weight by using less libraries.